# Какая должна быть архитектура видеосервера?

Tags: веб-программирование, streaming, online-video

Помогите с архитектурой видеосервера. Он должен принять видео потоки от камер по RTP (UDP), записывать видеоролики и одновременно на фронте должна быть возможность просмотра живого видео от выбранной камеры. Видео поток от камеры уже сжат кодеком, транскодировка не требуется, раскодировка видео ложится на клиент.

Comment: По отсутствию ответов на ваши предыдущие вопросы выскажу печальное предположение, что на этом сайте нет активных пользователей-специалистов по работе с видео (я тоже не специалист)

Comment: видимо да, не подскажите какие то профильные форумы?